# Uneven partitioner in kafka / no key

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have a topic with 3 partitions with only 1 consumer, and I am using the default partitioner which in this case is "Sticky". everything else by default.

The data sent from the producer does not have a key and I don't want it to have one, I simply want each data to go to a random partition and for these to be evenly distributed.

However I have a result similar to this, where one partition is way above the others
[image: Muestra]

As a result of this I have 2 questions.

- Why did this happen?
- How can I make the partitions to be equal again?

I have tried to create a custom partitioner that looks at the size of each partition and assigns the data where it has less data. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka documentation explains it:

> The DefaultPartitioner now uses a sticky partitioning strategy. This
> means that records for specific topic with null keys and no assigned
> partition will be sent to the same partition until the batch is ready
> to be sent. When a new batch is created, a new partition is chosen.
> This decreases latency to produce, but it may result in uneven
> distribution of records across partitions in edge cases. Generally
> users will not be impacted, but this difference may be noticeable in
> tests and other situations producing records for a very short amount
> of time.

Switching to the RoundRobinPartitionner (instead of DefaultPartitionner) is probably what you are looking for. See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_partitioner.class I ignore how constant your message rate, but under normal circumstances (Production) the Default partitionner is pretty fair.

Also ensure that `linger.ms` is `0` and reduce `batch.size` as much as you can.

Implementing a custom Partitionner is rather easy. But knowing which partition is the smaller is harder as it will change very often. You may end up spending more time refreshing partition sizes, and finding the smallest one that sending the message.